# How add 1billion rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table users (username, email, validts, confirmed.
I want add 1 billion unique rows

I tried to do this but it only adds 16 unique values

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, validts, confirmed)
SELECT 
    CONCAT('user', n) AS username,
    CONCAT('user', n, '@example.com') AS email,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 2592000 AS validts,
    0 AS confirmed
FROM 
    (SELECT @n := @n + 1 AS n FROM (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) t1, (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 10000) t2, (SELECT @n := 0) t3) numbers
LIMIT 1000000;
```

Comment: You're using php obviously.   Make a script .. Write a `for` loop in 20 seconds that will do that for you.

Comment: that will take forever to run no?

Comment: I would suspect so too; if you do this in PHP, it would either take forever to run, execution time limit would be hit (if set, some processes are `-1` or "infinite") or memory limit would be exhausted (again, if set.) All of these issues are compounded when you take "unique" into account. Unique numbers from 1 to 1,000,000,000, not too bad. Unique username and/or email over a billion rows, not as easy unless you use sequential values (like `user{X}` and `user{X}@example.com`, where `{X}` is 1 through 1 billion), as illustrated in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

in MySQL 5.7 this would work

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE populate (IN num INT)
       BEGIN
          WHILE num > 0 DO
            START TRANSACTION;
            INSERT INTO users (username, email, validts, confirmed)
            SELECT 
                CONCAT('user', cast(num as CHAR)),
                CONCAT('user', cast(num as CHAR), '@example.com'),
                FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 2592000),
                0;
            COMMIT;
            SET num = num - 1;
          END WHILE;
       END//

delimiter ;

call populate(1000000000);
```

but this will take very long time. you may try to move `START TRANSACTION` before `WHILE` loop, so MySQL will do one big transaction instead of 1 billion of small ones. That will speed it up a little bit, but in case of failure or Ctrl-C it will rollback all the inserted lines. Also disabling indexes on the table and disabling binlog would help a little bit. Beware, disabling binlog will break replication, if it takes place.
In more recent version you might be able to achieve this with recursive CTE. You generate CTE recursively until reaching 1 billion, and then insert into table from it. I think this should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this technique to generate Ns (and you can add other columns as you need):

```
create table dmy2 as 
select ((((T1.V)*10+T2.V)*10+T3.V)*10+T4.V)*10+T5.V as N
from       (values ROW (0),ROW (1),ROW (2),ROW (3),ROW (4),ROW (5),ROW (6),ROW (7),ROW (8),ROW (9)) T1(V)
cross join (values ROW (0),ROW (1),ROW (2),ROW (3),ROW (4),ROW (5),ROW (6),ROW (7),ROW (8),ROW (9)) T2(V)
cross join (values ROW (0),ROW (1),ROW (2),ROW (3),ROW (4),ROW (5),ROW (6),ROW (7),ROW (8),ROW (9)) T3(V)
cross join (values ROW (0),ROW (1),ROW (2),ROW (3),ROW (4),ROW (5),ROW (6),ROW (7),ROW (8),ROW (9)) T4(V)
cross join (values ROW (0),ROW (1),ROW (2),ROW (3),ROW (4),ROW (5),ROW (6),ROW (7),ROW (8),ROW (9)) T5(V)
```

You need to continue with the pattern to T9; I don't have any facility to test how long it takes, and you may need to perform some type-casting if the value of N overflows.